# How do I get function to return only numbers in numlist1 that are bigger than all numbers numlist2?

Tags: python

What I have so far:

```
def get_larger_numbers(numlist1,numlist2):
    new_list = []
    num = 0
    for num in numlist1:
        bigger_num = False
        for compare in numlist2:
            if num > compare:
                num1 = num
        new_list.append(num1)
    return new_list
```

Expected answer:

```
r_list = get_larger_numbers([4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 5])
print("Expected: [6, 10]")
```

Actual answer:

```
[4,6,10]
```

Answer (score 4):

Get the max of `numlist2` **once**, then filter `numlist1`:

```
numlist1, numlist2 = [4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 5]

M = max(numlist2)

out = [e for e in numlist1 if e>M]
```

###### as function

```
def get_larger_numbers(numlist1,numlist2):
    M = max(numlist2)
    return [e for e in numlist1 if e>M]

get_larger_numbers([4, 6, 10], [1, 3, 5])
# [6, 10]
```

###### fixing your function

even if it is inefficient due to the unnecessary multiple comparisons, here is how to fix your approach:

```
def get_larger_numbers(numlist1,numlist2):
    new_list = []
    num = 0
    for num in numlist1:
        bigger_num = True         # consider the number to keep by default
        for compare in numlist2:
            if num < compare:     # if we find a bigger number we won't add
                bigger_num = False
                break
        if bigger_num:            # should we add?
            new_list.append(num)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the biggest number in numlist2, then filter the numbers in numlist1 based on whether they are bigger than max_2.

```
def get_larger_numbers(numlist1,numlist2):
    max_2 = max(numlist2)
    return [x for x in numlist1 if x >max_2 ]
```